# If I uninstall an application from one administrator account in Windows 7, does it delete it for everybody?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

On one of the laptops I use, there are two administrator accounts. I created one for myself and one for a friend of mine.

If I were to uninstall a program, would that also uninstall the program on my friend's account?

Comment: Yes uninstalling it will delete it from both accounts as the program files(Folder actually containing the app) is common to all users. Uninstalling the app would delete the program from program files . So it will disappear from your friends account.

Comment: make sure if during the installation of that application there is not the option to make it available only to the current user. if there is, reainstall it on your friends account and remove it from yours. but in this case, wouldnt it be better to remove the supposedly annoying app icon you want to unistall? i mean, it will be on the hard drive anyway.

Answer (score 3):

When you uninstall any program from your hard disk.
It will uninstall both accounts because you have only one hard disk in your computer and 1 Windows (Operating System).

if you want to access only one account you can change the permission of your program or when you install it some application asking for all user or any specific user then you can decide it that time.

I hope It will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly Yes, But the preferences of each user is specific to his account. That is, the software personalize to each user of the computer. But if you uninstall the software the software, in most cases, will be removed for all the users.

If the software is annoying you, I am not sure how. I can assure you there are ways to keep it quiet for you.

Comment: There are exceptions, namely [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) programs, programs that don't write correct entries to the registry, or programs that **only** install for the current user, or programs that don't install on Program Files, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will remove the program for all accounts.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SuperUser. One line answers are not a common practise here. please elaborate on your answer.