# Windows 10: can an admin uninstall an application while it is in use by another user still signed in?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, remote-access

On a (remote) Windows 10 (1809) system, the user first signed in as *normal* user, then switched to *admin* user, without explicitly signing out the *normal* user.

At that point I connected remotely and uninstalled an application via start > settings > apps.

The application disappeared from the app list, but it turns out all the application's files are still present in the Program Files folder.

I cannot delete the files manually, as they appear in use by the *normal* user.

Would windows 10 allow an uninstall to proceed when an application is still being used by another user who is still signed in?

EDIT:

Ran into the same issue on a local tablet running Win 10 pro 1809, so without any remote access confusion. Here's how to reproduce the issue:

1. log in as normal user
2. open app-X
3. switch to admin user (without signing out normal user)
4. uninstall app-X (via settings->apps)

The uninstaller proceeds without errors, app X is removed from the list under settings->apps, but files remain in place in the `Program Files (x86)\app-X` folder.

NOTE: This was a custom app installed using an NSIS installer, haven't tried with other apps yet.

Comment: Yes it will remove the program for all accounts.
Check this https://superuser.com/questions/648379/if-i-uninstall-an-application-from-one-administrator-account-in-windows-7-does/648392

Comment: No. In fact, windows tells you that if you try to uninstall a program while another user is logged on that the program might not uninstall completely. Files that are in use can’t be changed.

Comment: Still, I confirmed the app was in use by the other user still signed in. The app was removed from the app list after running the uninstaller, without any message from windows that it could not proceed. The files remained in place. Could only remove the files manually after signing out the other user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you will be promoted to confirm you would like to do this as another use is using it.

Comment: Did not see any message though. It just proceeded with the uninstall, without any message, just silently leaving the files in place.

Comment: @djvg Was the user still logged in? It will only show a prompt if they are.

Comment: I guess so, because I was prevented from removing the app's folder from program files (as admin) because it was in use by another user.